# Variables for predicting price impact

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, transaction-costs, trade

Can anyone please recommend papers(other than Frazzini, 2017) that recommend market variables or any other predictors to model temporary price impact when you buy / sell a trade? This would fall under the TCA realm (Trade/ transaction Cost Analysis).

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify which Frazzini paper? On his website there's no paper in 2017, so you may be looking an earlier working paper